# How to combine two complex command using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

As per my requirement I have to merge two video's into one and add watermark into it.

This is working fine using below codes

1. Code to combine videos

   {"-y", "-i", inputFile1, "-i", inputFile2,
   "-filter_complex",
   "[0:v]scale="+res+",setsar=1[v0];" +
   "[1:v]scale="+res+",setsar=1[v1];" +
   "[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1",
   "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-s", ""+res, "-vcodec", "libx264",
   "-crf", "27", "-preset", "ultrafast", out_video.mp4}
2. Code to add watermark on merged video

   {"-y", "-i" ,out_video.mp4,
   "-i", "watermarg.png" ,
   "-filter_complex",
   "overlay=50:100", watermark_added.mp4}

My problem: Combine above command together to reduce execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it as a 3rd input and place overlay at the end.

Use

`{"-y", "-i", inputFile1, "-i", inputFile2, "-i", "watermark.png" , "-filter_complex", "[0:v]scale="+res+",setsar=1[v0];" + "[1:v]scale="+res+",setsar=1[v1];" + "[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v];" + "[v][2]overlay=50:100", "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-s", ""+res, "-vcodec", "libx264", "-crf", "27", "-preset", "ultrafast", out_video.mp4}`